# How to get URI value coming from HTML to Variable in Spring (There are multiple Links associated with corresponding method)

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have multiple  links in my HTML, which are referring to URI in Controller Class,

How can I get this URI in some variable which can be used further, at last, I want to store these URI in DB.

HTML Code :

```
<td><a href="/ui/report/win">Win Report</a></td>

<td><a href="/ui/report/niw">Win Report</a></td>
```

Spring Controller Class :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/ui/report/win", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String winReport() {
    return "win_report";
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/ui/report/niw", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String niwReport() {
    return "niw_report";
}
```

Comment: You are already have URL in @RequestMapping(value="/ui/report/win"). Why you need to read again from request?

Comment: You declared `winReport` two times, i suppose this is a typo?

Comment: Yes, Corrected.

Comment: I want to save this value of @RequestMapping , in DB each time user perform a click on the link.(Tracking all user activity something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below solution to retrieve the page Url as well as avoid using repetitive method calls.

```
You can use a Spring Boot HandlerInterceptor, here's a brief description of the same :

Handler interceptors are used when you want to apply specific
functionality to certain or all requests. 


Handler Interceptors should implement the interface HandlerInterceptor. HandlerInterceptor can be used to avoid repetitive handler code. 

We can use HandlerInterceptor for different purposes like authorization checks, locale checks, logging, creating common application parameters etc.

HandlerInterceptor works similar to the servlet filter. But in some cases filters are more powerful than HandlerInterceptor. 
In Spring-MVC the HandlerInterceptor is configured in spring application context xml file or by Java configuration.

HandlerInterceptor has three methods. 

        preHandle( ) : It is executed before actual handler is executed. 
        postHandle( ) : It is executed after handler is executed. 
        afterCompletion( ) : It is executed after the complete request is finished.
```

For more details, you can use an example from the below link

https://www.tuturself.com/posts/view?menuId=3&postId=1071

You can get the entire sample project which can help you with the setup at

https://github.com/ninja-panda

Answer (score 0):

To get the request url you can do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ui/report/win", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String winReport(HttpServletRequest request){
    String request = request.getRequestURI();
    // do somehting here
    return "win_report"
}
```

Spring will automatically inject the `HttpServletRequest`.

**Update:**

If your want get the urls for all of your methods in your controller, you can go with `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`:

```
private final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

@Autowired
public YourController(RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping) {
    this.handlerMapping = handlerMapping;
}
```

With `handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods()`, you can access all mappings decleared in your controller. With reflection and [`getMappingAnnotation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html#getMethodAnnotation-java.lang.Class-), you can then read the value of each `RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: Thank you, I used this approach but it looks repeated when there are multiple URI to refer.

Comment: @HargunSuri What do you mean by multiple URIs? Multiple methods in your controller?

Comment: Yes, Correct, there are multiple methods in my controller around 10 to 15.

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe this is what your are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I will try if this helps me

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `getServletPath()` like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ui/report/win", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String winReport(HttpServletRequest request){
    String mapping = request.getServletPath();
    // do somehting here
    System.out.println(mapping); // Will print /ui/report/win
    return "win_report"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Sudhir, what can be done if there are multiple methods in controller class and each method is associated with some HTML link,  Here I have 10 - 15 methods, I want to make this generic.